# what is the joint distribution of these two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

what is the joint distribution of two random variables,$∑_iX_iY_i$ and $(∑_iX_i)(∑_jY_j)$?

Note that since $n$ is a large number and all the random variables are $iid$, using central limit theorem, we can say that $∑_iX_iY_i$, $(∑_iX_i)$ and $(∑_jY_j)$ are approximately normal random variables and $(∑_iX_i)$$(∑_jY_j)$ is the product of two normal random variables which would have *Normal Product Distribution*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $X_i$ are iid then $\sum X_i$ is *not* approximately normal, check carefully the statement of the CLT, so your statements about the limiting case are not correct.

Secondly, if $X_i$ are not independent, you have to know their joint distribution to know the dependence structure between them. Knowing the joint distribution of a random vector $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$, you can easily recover the distribution of a function of this vector
$$
f(X_1,\dots,X_n) := \sum X_i.
$$

In case $X_i$ are independent, you have
$$
  \mathsf P(X_1+X_2\leq t) = \int_\Bbb R F_2(t-x_1)\mathrm dF_1(x_1)
$$
where $F_i$ is a CDF of $X_i$. I hope, you know how to extend this formula to the case of more than $2$ variable by induction.

Finally, when you need to deal with products you have 
$$
  \mathsf P(XY\leq t) = \int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(Xy\leq t)\mathrm dF_Y(y) 
$$
$$
= \int_0^\infty F_X(t/y)\mathrm dF_y(y)+\int_{-\infty}^0 (1-F_X(t/y))\mathrm dF_Y(y) + 1\{t\geq 0\}\cdot\mathsf P(Y = 0).
$$
I think, you now have all ingridients.

Comment: I wonder why ∑Xi is not approximately normal?!

Comment: @May: because only $\frac{\sum (X_i - \mu)}{\sigma\sqrt n}$ is. When you multiply this by $\sqrt n$, approximation is too rough. More precisely, $\sum X_i$ does not have to converge in distribution to the normal one.

Comment: how can I find the joint distribution of these two random variables?

Comment: e.g. for the simple case that you discussed ( XY and X+Y)

Comment: @May: you can edit your comments within 5 minutes after you posted them, so no need to write clarifiction separately. W.r.t. your question about the joint distribution - I didn't get it, could you be more specific?

Comment: How can I find P( XY +(X+Y)<= t) ?